# Complex find conditions includes ''include"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-2

I'm developeing with Rails 2.3.8 Ruby 1.8.7 and PostgreSQL.
I want to search records by relation.

**UserGuildMaster**

```
class UserGuildMaster < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :leader, :foreign_key => 'guild_id', :class_name => 'UserGuildLog', :conditions => {:leader_flag => 1, :status => 1}
    has_many :user_guild_logs, :foreign_key => 'guild_id', :class_name => 'UserGuildLog'
end
```

**UserGuildLog**

```
class UserGuildLog < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :guild, :class_name => "UserGuildMaster"
    belongs_to :user_master
    belongs_to :user_character, :class_name => "UserCharacter"
end
```

**UserCharacter**

```
class UserCharacter < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I want to search **UserGuildMaster** which **leader.user_character.logined_at is before 5days** and which **has less than 10 user_guild_logs**.

My find conditions is below, but it raise error **'PGError: ERROR:  schema "leader"'does not exist.**

```
  @user_guild_masters = UserGuildMaster.find(:all, :include => [{:leader => :user_character}, :user_guild_logs], 
    :conditions => ['leader.user_character.logined_at < ? AND user_guild_logs.size < ?', 5.days.ago, 10]
  )
```

This Rails project is now on service and can't add or change column.
I have no idea to finde these related records. Any ideas?

Comment: The error says it all, really. You don't have a schema called "leader" defined. Possible causes include: You're not running against the database you think you are; your schema is called `"Leader"` or `"LEADER"` not `leader` (see `\dn` in `psql`); you're trying to use the `schemaname.tablename.columname` syntax as if it were some kind of implicit join path expression like the (wrong) `tablename1.tablename2.columnname`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually I guess the problem is that the relation name and table name is not match. I'll check more in a few days.